# Why does imagemagick's magick command require two arguments for its -write argument?

Tags: imagemagick

I've installed ImageMagick v7.0.10-26 on to Windows and I'm running it from a cmd line. I've not installed `convert`.

This example creates two new image files, modified as specified, from the `existingimage.png`:

```
magick existingimage.png -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 150 -annotate +0+20 "Hello World" -write newimage1.gif newimage2.gif
```

When I remove `newimage2.gif` from the command, then `magick` complains (and output no images) with:

```
magick: MissingArgument `-write' at CLI arg 11 @ fatal/magick-cli.c/ProcessCommandOptions/447.
```

Why does `-write` require two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does `-write` require two parameters?

It doesn't. It requires [one parameter](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#write%60), an "intermediate" output file name.

You appear to be misunderstanding the "final" (fully processed) output file name (e.g. `newimage2.gif`) as being part of `-write`, which it is not. Any final output file name is typically the last parameter for `magick ...`:

```
# Create both an "intermediate" image processed with the 
# options up to "-write filename" ("newimage1.gif") and 
# a separate "final" image ("newimage2.gif") with those 
# same options.

magick existingimage.png -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 150 -annotate +0+20 "Hello World" -write newimage1.gif newimage2.gif

# Create just a "final" image, processed with all the 
# existing options in the given "magick" command.
# (no "-write filename" command needed)

magick existingimage.png -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 150 -annotate +0+20 "Hello World" newimage2.gif

# Create both an "intermediate" image processed with the 
# options up to "-write filename" ("newimage1.gif") and 
# a separate "final" image ("newimage2.gif") with additional 
# options unique to it ("-resize 50%"). 

magick existingimage.png -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 150 -annotate +0+20 "Hello World" -write newimage1.gif -resize 50% newimage2.gif

# This produces an error. The "final" file name here for 
# "magick ..." is "newimage1.gif" and "-write" has no 
# "intermediate" file name specified.

magick existingimage.png -gravity south -fill white -pointsize 150 -annotate +0+20 "Hello World" -write newimage1.gif
```

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. This is the right answer.